# Access denied to Service Applications page in Central Administration

Tags: central-administration, farm, service-applications

I have farm admin permissions to a dev farm of on premises SP 2019 installation. The problem is that while I can access most of the features of Central Administration, whenever I access the Manage Service Applications feature (/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx), I'm getting Access Denied message. Any idea what that might be?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Access is denied. 
  Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL. 

 Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to launch IE or the Central Admin start menu shortcut 'As Administrator'. It won't automatically elevate. Or access CA from a remote machine.

You also need to be a Local Admin on each SharePoint server.